# Select two datacolumns from a datarow in linq (vb.net 3.5)

Tags: vb.net, linq, select, multiple-columns

```
Dim orders = From tt In testTable _
             Order By tt.Item("OrderNumber") _
             Select tt.Item("OrderNumber"), tt.Item("OrderId")
```

This is breaking. Is there a way to do this? I would have thought it was easy enough. Obviously, I thought wrong....

Answer (score 6, accepted):

```
Dim orders = From tt In testTable _
     Order By tt.Item("OrderNumber") _
     Select New With {.OrderNo = tt.Item("OrderNumber"), .OrderId = tt.Item("OrderId")}
```

If I got the VB.NET syntax right

This returns an anonymous type, if you want to return an existing type you replace `With` with that type.

Comment: I had a similar solution:

Dim projects = From tt In testTable _
               Order By tt.Item("ProjectName") _
               Select ProjectName = tt.Item("ProjectName"), ProjectId = tt.Item("ProjectId") _
               Distinct